# PlotProjects notifications are open automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, plot, push-notification

I'm having a problem with the PlotProjects library because notifications open automatically, so my users are complaining that it's very invasive.

How can I correct this behavior?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    SentNotification notification = null;
    try {
        notification = intent.getParcelableExtra("notification");
        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
        launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        launchIntent.putExtra(PLOT_RECEIVE_EVENT, notification.getData());
        launchIntent.putExtra(RECEIVER, PLOT_RECEIVER);
        context.startActivity(launchIntent);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        if (notification != null)
            Crashlytics.log(TAG + notification.toString());
        else
            Crashlytics.log(TAG + " Notification was empty");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Esteban, what do you mean by "opening automatically"? Do they open without the user explicitly clicking on the notification?

Comment: Yes, when a user is alerted by a notification from a Beacons, the app is open without the user explicitly clicking on the notification. @Sampaio

Comment: That is indeed curious Esteban, in our SDK, all the available actions (open app, url or deeplink) that we provide are triggered after the user explicitly clicks the notification. Could it be possible that the app employs some type of logic that opens an activity when a push notification is received? Does it happen in different devices? If you could provide me with a link to the APK, so that I can help you in a more informed way

Comment: @Sampaio I update my question with de code in the BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Thanks for the update Esteban. The onReceive method is only called when a user clicks on the notification, as you can verify by running our Example App that comes with the SDK, so in that sense the code inside the onReceive method should not be run before the user clicks. If you can provide me with more info, would be easier to help. We can also move this discussion to our Intercom chat, which can be accessed through the Plot Projects dashboard where we could interact better and faster.